# iis Machine key on server level

Tags: windows, iis

I am currently working on automating the setup of a new IIS server, and I've encountered a challenge regarding adding a server-level Machine Key using PowerShell. While I'm aware of the method to configure the Machine Key on a per-application basis within the web.config file, regrettably, this approach is not applicable to my specific scenario.
(Machine Key the same across multiple servers)

I would like some guidance on how to do the task of adding the Machine Key  and configuring settings on server-level through PowerShell.

Thank you so much for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since those are stored in ASP.NET root `web.config` files, you can directly manipulate them as XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According @YurongDai [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77131560/14832311)

The command, in my case, should look like that.

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:machineKey /validation:HMACSHA512 /decryption:AES /validationKey:<yourValidationKey> /decryptionKey:<yourDecryptionKey>
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/wmi-provider/machinekeysection-class)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up machine key encryption by using the UI, running the appcmd.exe command, editing the configuration file directly, or writing a WMI script.

You can set machine key encryption at the global level using the appcmd.exe command:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:machineKey /validation:HMACSHA256
```

Note: When configuring using Appcmd.exe the `/commit:WEBROOT` switch must be included in the  element at the global level in IIS in order to make configuration changes to the root web.config file instead of the ApplicationHost.config.

You can also enter the following command in PowerShell to configure:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT' -filter 'system.web/machineKey' -name 'validation' -value 'AES'
```

Note: The default machine key verification method is SHA256.